# Chartkick with months name as axis

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, chartkick

I am new in ruby and I am having a problem using Chartkick. I am using this code

```
<%= area_chart  MediaDownload.select("COUNT(*) as count_all , monthname(created_at) as created_at").group('created_at') %>
```

What I want to achieve is to get a area chart with information per month (displaying month names), but instead I am receiving this graphic

[image]

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Chartkick does not support a discrete axis for line or area charts.  You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/68